# Jenkins-Testlink HTTP server returned unexpected status: Authorization Required

Tags: plugins, jenkins, authorization, xml-rpc, testlink

I have installed jenkins 1.5 and testlink 1.9.5 (which are on my computer, call it machineA).
 I have installed testlink 1.9.2 which is on a server (call it machineB).

When I’m trying to connect Jenkins (1.5) with TestLink (1.9.5) thru Jenkins configuration in order to retrieve tests, it works perfectly.

But when I’m trying to connect Jenkins (1.5) with TestLink (1.9.2), while running the job in Jenkins I get the below error in the console :

```
FATAL: Error verifying developer key: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Authorization Required
br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException: Error verifying developer key: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Authorization Required
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:66)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestLinkAPI.<init>(TestLinkAPI.java:162)
    at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.getTestLinkSite(TestLinkBuilder.java:244)
    at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.perform(TestLinkBuilder.java:134)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:810)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:592)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1568)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransportException: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Authorization Required
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.getInputStream(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:94)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:152)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.BaseService.executeXmlRpcCall(BaseService.java:90)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:62)
    ... 12 more
ERROR: Erreur de communication avec TestLink. Vérifiez votre configuration de TestLink.
Enregistrement des résultats des tests
Finished: FAILURE
```

How could I solve this prblm? Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with DEV-KEY:

```
FATAL: Error verifying developer key: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Authorization Required
br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException: Error verifying developer key: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Authorization Required
```

I think you can try generate new dev key and try again.